# Magento 2 Import/Export Options Missing

Tags: magento2, module, import, migration, export

I've installed **Magento 2** and under

> **System -> Data Transfer**

there are no options.
 Do I have to **enable** them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure the admin user has access to Role Resources, **System → Data Transfer** with all the options checked or selected. Otherwise, the options will not be listed on the admin menu in the admin page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the user has full access

Comment: I assume there is no way to disable the options right? I've just realised that the theme i'm using has an import demo function, so it's probably overwriting it.

Comment: Yeah there's a way to disable it. Navigate from **System → Permissions→ User Roles→ Role{Administrators}→ Role Resources→ Resource Access**

Comment: yeah could be..

Comment: I disabled everything, i'm in developer mode and i still can't see anything. Also no Magento logs, no webserver logs. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to modify the resource access of your user? and enable only the Import and Export?

Comment: Yes, i created new roles only for the data transfer section and for a new user, but still nothing.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of it? let's see what we can do otherwise you have to create a new admin and test if it works form him