# No Import/Export Section under System->Data Transfer

Tags: import, magento2.4, admin-panel, export, importexport

In the Admin-Panel there should a "Import/Export" option under System->Data Transfer. This option is missing for me.

[image: Missing Import]

I have already checked Admin-Resources and the admin-user has access to them all.

The answers in [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325708/missing-import-export-options-under-system-data-transfer-magento-ce-2-4-1) suggest changing values in the core-config-data table but I don't have any entries in my table, with the paths referenced there, at all.

The Magento ImportExport module is enabled.

What else could cause this?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/266486/82670

Comment: @Msquare I have already tried everything concerning admin-resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the values of bellow fields from 1 to 0 in the core_config_data table

> advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_Integration
> advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_TaxImportExport
> advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_ImportExport